# What is the list of free bank house appraisal like the Chase home value estimator?

Tags: real-estate

What is the list of free bank house appraisal in US like the Chase home value estimator?

I want good ones like the chase.

Comment: Would the country where the house is situated be at all relevant to any answers people might give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a free way to do an estimate:

1. Find a house in the same neighborhood that sold within the last few months or the last year.
2. Look up on the local government website what the tax appraisal was for the house that was sold.
3. You now have a ratio of tax appraisal to selling price.
4. Look up the apprised value for the house you want to estimate.
5. Use the ratio to estimate the selling price.

You can use several houses in the first two steps to get a range of ratios.

If you are selling or buying a house, your agent can help with this process. If you don't have an agent yet, this is one of the key questions to ask potential agents.